# JQuery: Table Row Show/Hide based on Column Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, razor

I have a table that has a column with Yes/No as possible values

```
<table id="mytable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Col1
    </th>
    <th>
        Col2
    </th>

    <th>
        ActiveYN
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        Apple
    </td>
    <td>
        12345
    </td>

    <td>
        Yes
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Orange
    </td>
    <td>
        67890
    </td>

    <td>
        No
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Mango
    </td>
    <td>
        456745
    </td>

    <td>
        Yes
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to show the row if ActiveYN is 'Yes' and Hide id ActiveYN is 'No'
How can i access the ActiveYN inside JQuery and show/hide accordingly?

Comment: please provide the rendered html code

Comment: Would make more sense to post the HTML and not the ASP, as jQuery is clientside and changes the HTML, not your severside code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PsvrW/)

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var $rowsNo = $('#mytable tbody tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(2).text()) === "No"
    }).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

How about something like this: `$('td:contains("No")').parent().hide();`

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RZ6yw/1/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
$('input').click(function(){
    $('td:contains("No")').parent().toggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='button' value='hide/show' />

<table id="mytable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>
        Col1
    </th>
    <th>
        Col2
    </th>

    <th>
        ActiveYN
    </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
        Apple
    </td>
    <td>
        12345
    </td>

    <td>
        Yes
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Orange
    </td>
    <td>
        67890
    </td>

    <td>
        No
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        Mango
    </td>
    <td>
        456745
    </td>

    <td>
        No
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

usually I would add this as an attribute on the row:

```
<tr data-active="No">
....
</tr>
```

Then to hide them all you can do:

```
$(function(){

$("[data-active=No]").hide();
});
```

Or you can add different classes/styles based on the value when it creates the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from server side itself.

```
@if (item.ActiveYN) {
    <tr style="display: none;">
} else {
    <tr>
}
```

I don't know the razor syntax, but you get the idea.

To be able to do it from client-side, add a class.

```
@if (item.ActiveYN) {
    <tr class="hideMe">
} else {
    <tr>
}
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$('.hideMe').hide();
```

**Edited** again after your question was edited, now if we forget the server-side altogether:

```
$("mytable").find("tr:contains('No')").hide();
```

Use this statement in your button click handler function. But, remember it will also find any text which contains "No" anywhere in a row. To make it more precise, use regular expressions to search exactly a "No".

Comment: But then it would be static, not depending of user's interaction

Comment: Edited the answer. Now you can use it from client-side.

Comment: actually i should have posted plain html earlier, now i posted. i will put a button to hide or show.

Comment: @Seenu You have edited the question and removed the server-side code. This will change the very context of the answer which was based on your server-side html generation.

Comment: @Seenu See the edited answer based on your new question context.