# Use JQuery to hide table rows that do not match the text in a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When the user clicks on a chevron (button), I want the jquery to hide all table rows that do not contain the text within the chevron.

I tried some code, posted below, but it doesn't work.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qw959Lr0/)

Code:

```
$(function () {
 $('#chevrons > ul > li > a').click( function(){
 $('#chevrons .selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
 $('#show-all').removeAttr("style");
 $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
  var $chev = $(this).text();
  var $rowsNo = $('#sales-opportunities tbody tr').filter(function () {
        return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(4).text()) === $chev
        }).toggle();
});

$(function () {
    $('#show-all').click( function(){
    $('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).css('color', '#FECF2A');
 });
});
```

Stripped down HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12">      
<div id="chevrons">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Prospect</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Qualifying</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Demonstrating</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Negotiating</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;">
            Closed
          </a></li>
      <li id="dormant"><a href="#" onclick="return false;">Dormant
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-2" style="height: 1px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a href="#" onclick="return false;" id="show-all">Show All Opportunities</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped display responsive no-wrap dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" id="sales-opportunities" role="grid" aria-describedby="sales-opportunities_info">
    <thead>
        <tr role="row"><th class="sorting_asc" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-sort="ascending" aria-label="Opportunity Name: activate to sort column descending" style="width: 235px;">Opportunity Name</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Company: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 120px;">Company</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Value: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 117px;">Value</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Close Date: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 181px;">Close Date</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Pipeline Status: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 185px;">Pipeline Status</th><th class="sorting" tabindex="0" aria-controls="sales-opportunities" rowspan="1" colspan="1" aria-label="Action: activate to sort column ascending" style="width: 90px;">Action</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>


    <tr role="row" class="odd">
                <td class="sorting_1"><a href="/sales_opportunities/20">Product for China</a></td>
                <td><a href="/companies/99">China</a></td>
                <td>$100,000.00</td>
                <td>Wed, 19 Nov 2014</td>
                <td>Closed won</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="/sales_opportunities/20/edit">edit</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr><tr role="row" class="even">
                <td class="sorting_1"><a href="/sales_opportunities/21">Another product for China</a></td>
                <td><a href="/companies/99">China</a></td>
                <td>$35,000.00</td>
                <td>Thu, 27 Nov 2014</td>
                <td>Demonstrating</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-warning" href="/sales_opportunities/21/edit">edit</a>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr></tbody>
</table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I borrowed the code to hide rows from this stackoverflow answer: [hide row based on column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722205/jquery-table-row-show-hide-based-on-column-value) - and whilst I know this would do the opposite of what I'm asking for (i.e. this would hide the row containing the text in my chevron) it isn't actually doing anything at all on my page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it would be much easier if you would add classes to rows (like prospect/qualifying etc) meaning the chevrons of yours would make classes for rows, and when clicked you would take chevron innerHtml and hide all rows expected the class of your chevron HTML

Comment: you need exact text or contains?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/32bitkid/qw959Lr0/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [DEMO (http://jsfiddle.net/11b2g0L2/1/)](http://jsfiddle.net/11b2g0L2/1/)

Added css class

```
tr.hiddenRow
{
    display:none;
}
```

Some JS added

```
var allRows = $('.table-responsive table tbody tr');
        allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
        var clickedText = $(this).text();
        allRows.each(function(){
            //$(this).contains
            if( ! $(this).is(':contains("'+clickedText+'")'))  {
                $(this).addClass('hiddenRow');
            }
        });
```

Added some dummy rows

You should enter equal values in thead and tbody rows
like 'Closed won' and 'closed' are not equal , So I have changed, and added some rows for `negotiating` and `qualifying`

Comment: Thanks - that seems to do what I need. Is there a way to show all rows when no chevron is selected (I see that clicking "show all opportunities" does this, but I'd like it to work when the chevron is deselected too.

Comment: Also I think I'll split the closed won and closed lost chevron into two, so that it works better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: you can add login like if `selected` class is not there then remove `hiddenRow`.

Comment: I will do. At the moment it's not working on my page (even though it works in the jsfiddle). On my page the js is adding 'hiidenRow' to every row, not just the ones that don't match the clickedText. Any idea why that might happen? (I literally just copy/pasted the js out of your jsfiddle, so it's not a typo).

Comment: Worked it out - I had whitespace all over the text (plus a span class with numbers in that I didn't include in the fiddle). So in the end I var clickedText = $(this).clone()    
        .children() 
        .remove()   
        .end() 
        .text() 
        .trim();

Comment: Which allows the "Closed" button to show up both closed won and closed lost. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qw959Lr0/2/;

jquery:

```
$(function () {

var allRows = $('.table-responsive table tbody tr');

$('#chevrons > ul > li > a').click( function(){

$('#chevrons .selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
$('#show-all').removeAttr("style");

var $this = $(this),
    classname = $this.text().toLowerCase().trim();


$this.toggleClass('selected'); 
allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
if($this.hasClass('selected'))
{    
$.each(allRows,function(i,item)
       {
           $(item).hasClass(classname) ? '' : $(item).addClass('hiddenRow');
       });
}
});
$('#show-all').click( function(){
  $('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).css('color', '#FECF2A');
     allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
});
});
```

i added classes and it works just fine. If you take items from database i think they should have category names and adding classes according to that category(chevrons) should not be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, but in the jsfiddle you shared clicking on any button causes some of the content to hide. "Prospect" causes "Demonstrating" objects to hide, and all other chevrons cause "Closed Won" to hide. Any idea how to make this so that the row ONLY shows if the respective button is clicked (e.g. if I click on "won" then only rows with "closed won" show and everything else is hidden)?

Answer (score 0):

First thing is that the approach which you have used will work sometimes not every time. Because at this line return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(4).text()) === $chev you are checking the text of anchor element with the text of td:eq(4) from your table.which migth be different sometimes.such as when we will click on closed button it will check for the text `'closed' === 'closed won'` which returns you `false` always.

Solution for your problem: 
Let us assume that whatever HTML you have created will not change in future. 
so you can add the classes to td:eq(4) as per the chevrons text, according to this your

`<td>Demonstrating</td>` will change to `<td class="demonstrating">Demonstrating</td>`
and others will also get changed accordingly. Now you have to set data attributes to your links from the li element.So your entire UL for chevrons button will changed as follow:

```
<ul>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'prospect'>Prospect</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'qualifying'>Qualifying</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'demonstrating'>Demonstrating</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'negotiating'>Negotiating</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'closed'>
            Closed
          </a></li>
      <li id="dormant"><a href="#" onclick="return false;" data-attribute_name_you_like = 'dormant'>Dormant
        </a></li>
    </ul>
```

Now finally you have to change your onclick function as follow:

```
  $(function () {
    $('#chevrons > ul > li > a').click( function(){
        $('#chevrons .selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
        $('#show-all').removeAttr("style");
        $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        // instead of taking the text now we will take the data-attribute_name_what_you_like
        //var $chev = $(this).text();

        var $chev = $(this).attr('data-attribute_name_you_like');

    // creating class syntax for td according to clicked button
    var $tdClassName = $chev;
    $('#sales-opportunities td.'+ $tdClassName).closest('tr').toggle();

        /*var $rowsNo = $('#sales-opportunities tbody tr').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(4).text()) === $chev
            }).toggle();*/
    });
});
```

I have kept your code in commented so you can easily understand what changes I have made. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, thanks to TechnoKrol's solution above, I finally got the solution working. Thanks to everyone who commented to help. The working solution on my site is as follows (for reference):

```
$(function () {
var allRows = $('.table-responsive table tbody tr');
$('#chevrons > ul > li > a').click(function () {
    $('#chevrons .selected').not(this).removeClass('selected');
    $('#show-all').removeAttr("style");
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    $(this).click(function() {
    if (! $(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
    }
});

    allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
    var clickedText = $(this).clone()    
                            .children() 
                            .remove()   
                            .end() 
                            .text() 
                            .trim();        
    allRows.each(function(){
        //$(this).contains
        if( ! $(this).is(':contains("'+clickedText+'")'))  {
            $(this).addClass('hiddenRow');
        }
    });       
  });
});

$(function () {
  $('#show-all').click(function () {
    $('#chevrons .selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).css('color', '#FECF2A');
    var allRows = $('.table-responsive table tbody tr');
    allRows.removeClass('hiddenRow');
  });
});
```