# Hide rows in JSP and based on values in a column

Tags: jquery, jsp

I have a table in JSP which displays the contents of a list in the following way:

```
<tbody>
    <c:forEach items="${A_List}" varStatus="status" var="alist">
        <tr role="row" id="colorRow">
            <td>${alist.A}</td>
            <td>${alist.B}</td
            <td>${alist.C}</td>
            <td id="ID1">${alist.D}</td>
        </tr>    
    </c:forEach>
</tbody>
```

Now the column D will be displaying several strings. I want to hide certain rows based on the value displayed. Let's say I just want to show the records which have the value "SHOWME" and hide the rest. I'm using the following jQuery code for that:

```
$(function agreed(){
    var arr=[];

    $("#ID1").each(function(){
        arr.push($(this).text());
    });

    $.each(arr,function(index,value){
        if(value != "AGREED"){
            ("#this").parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

However, nothing seems to happen. Now, here somehow it's being marked as a duplicate. But the answer to the question to which it is marked as a Duplicate doesn't work in my case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: Table Row Show/Hide based on Column Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722205/jquery-table-row-show-hide-based-on-column-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues. First of all, the `id` attribute is intended to provide a **unique** identifier for an element, so you shouldn't be doing `<td id="ID1">...</td>` inside of a looping JSP tag. Use the `class` attribute instead.

Second, you create an array containing all of the text of the columns you're looking at. That's great, but it doesn't really do anything for you. There's no way to work backwards from the string to the specific element it came from.

Later on, you do `$('#this').parent().hide()`, which looks for an element with ID "this" (doesn't exist), gets the parent of any matched elements (there are none), and tries to hide them (no elements selected so does nothing).

What you could instead do is this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.ID1').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() != 'AGREED';
    }).parent().hide();
});
```

That selects all of the `<td>` elements with the class (not id - see above on why you need to change it) of "ID1", filters them down to the ones where their text content doesn't match the values you want to keep, gets their parent element (the entire row), then hides them.

Comment: Yes. This works. But, kind of. My table is actually a DataTable. So, it hides the records, but I still get the option to go to the next 10 records and the hidden records are then shown there.

Comment: @AbhineetKumar In that case you'd need to call the code after the next 10 records have been loaded, not just when the page loads.

Comment: All the records are loaded when the page is loaded. The records are sent to the JSP as a list and then displayed 10 at a time in a Data table as I have mentioned in the code. So, when I run ur Script, it hides the records from the first 10 results and then shows them later on.